# Android - Adding a GridLayout inside a FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I am trying to use the Library SwipeLayout (https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) to make a table of swipeable rows (that is, to achieve [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/183f464b177ffa9d0b35f396796ec64f37ce87db/687474703a2f2f7777312e73696e61696d672e636e2f6d773639302f36313064633033346a7731656a6f7175696476767367323038693036333075342e676966) effect). I want to create the table dynamically (with Java, not xml). The table (if it were to exist as xml) should look like this:

```
...TableLayout...
<TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swipe"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <!-- The first view in SwipeLayout is the delete button hidden behind -->
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:id="@+id/delete1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:background="#FF0000"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:text="Delete"/>

                    <GridLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/bottom_border_light_solid"
                            android:columnCount="2"
                            android:padding="10dp">

                        ...TextViews...

                    </GridLayout>

                </com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>

            </TableRow>
.../TableLayout...
```

My table creation code looks like this:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(c);
SwipeLayout swipeLayout = new SwipeLayout(c);
TextView delete = generateDeleteButton(c); //I have confirmed that this function works
GridLayout cell = generateRoutineLayout(c); //I have confirmed that this function works

swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.LayDown);
swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, delete);
swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(swipeListener);

cell.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

swipeLayout.addView(delete);
swipeLayout.addView(cell);

TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
swipeLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

row.addView(swipeLayout);
TableRow.LayoutParams rl = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
row.setLayoutParams(rl);//TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
row.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I have confirmed that generateRoutineLayout(c) works properly and generates a correct GridLayout. After closely inspecting the Tree View in Android monitor it is clear that the grid layout IS added to the SwipeLayout and IS properly sized, but it is simply not appearing!

I know that SwipeLayout extends FrameLayout. Is it possible that I can't insert a GridLayout into a FrameLayout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try having `RelativeLayout` inside your `FrameLayout` and then add your `GridLayout` inside the `RelativeLayout`.

Hope this helps you.